# Algorithm to find all 2-hop neighbors lists in a graph

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, graphs, randomized-algorithms

Given a graph $G = (V,E)$, where $|V| = n$. What is a fast algorithm for generating the collection of all 2-hop neighborhood lists of all nodes in $V$.

Naively, you can do that in $O(n^3)$. With power of matrices, you can do that with $O(n^{2.8})$ using Strassen algorithm. You can do better than this using another matrix multiplication algorithm. Any better method ? Any Las Vegas algorithm ?

Comment: There is a O(n^2) deterministic algorithm.

Comment: @MikeG how to do that ?

Comment: @MikeG has found a marvelous quadratic time matrix multiplication algorithm which unfortunately is too small to fit within a stackexchange comment

Comment: @SashoNikolov Can you give a reference?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The question really depends on what is the precise definition of a 2-hop. If by a 2-hop you mean the set $$hp(v) = \{ u \mid \mbox{there is a path of length 2 between u and v}\},$$ then the current answer is no, you cannot do it faster than $O(n^{\omega})$ where $\omega$ is the usual constant associated with the complexity of performing the matrix product.

Why? For every vertex $v$ check if $v$ is adjacent to vertex in $hp(v).$ If this is the case then you have found a triangle in your graph. Moreover the graph is triangle free if you do not find a vertex $v$ with this property.

The currently best known algorithm for testing if a graph is triangle-free has time complexity $O(n^{\omega}).$

Comment: Interesting, do you have a reference for the triangle-free recognition problem. Is there a proven lower bound for this problem ?

Comment: No there is no proven lower bound but recently, a very surprising connection was found. If you can detect triangles faster than $O(n^{\omega})$ then you can compute the matrix product faster than $O(n^{\omega})$. See the paper "Triangle Detection Versus Matrix Multiplication: A study of Truly Subcubic Reducibility" by Williams and Williams. Here http://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/cla/tria-mmult.pdf

Comment: Neat, glad it helped!